# Java Android Get the name of a collection from the Firestore Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve the name of the first collection that appears in "userPosts":

[image]

I then tried to do this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("post").document(listUserId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + task.getResult().getString("userPosts"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

But the result is "null".

Is there a way to get the name of the first collection in userPosts (which is a document)?

Comment: So what exactly would you like to get, the ID of the document, which is `3f*b...a!jz`?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes the ID of the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the name of the `3f*b...a!jz` document, you need to create a reference that points to the `userPosts` collection and then use a `get()` call, as you can see in the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference userPostsRef = rootRef.collection("post").document(listUserId).collection("userPosts");
userPostsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Log.d(TAG, document.getId());
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
3f*b...a!jz
```

Comment: Is it possible to limit the results to 1 and get the first in userPosts or do I have to make a query?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can add a `limit(1)` call and save it in a `Query` rather than a `CollectionReference` object.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much! I was able to solve the problem with your help